# How to make BeginGetRequestStream and BeginGetResponse really asynchronous?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, synchronous

I'm working on an industrial web module that has to asynchronously login to a web server and later send small requests for data. 
First I send a GET request to receive the session cookie, then a POST request with UN and PW.
I want to use the BeginGetRequestStream and BeginGetResponse methods from the HttpWebRequest class. However, if you read the quotes from MSDN below, it mentions some parts are not async.

How should I deal with this problem the best way? Should I avoid using these methods completely, or should I build in a fail-safe mechanism so that in case the methods take to long the code just skips on (if that is even possible)?
Coding effort is not an issue, the important thing is to ensure my module is truly async and will never block the main program.

Thanks!

> The BeginGetRequestStream method requires some synchronous setup tasks
>   to complete (DNS resolution, proxy detection, and TCP socket
>   connection, for example) before this method becomes asynchronous. As a
>   result, this method should never be called on a user interface (UI)
>   thread because it might take considerable time (up to several minutes
>   depending on network settings) to complete the initial synchronous
>   setup tasks before an exception for an error is thrown or the method
>   succeeds.
>
> The BeginGetResponse method requires some synchronous setup tasks to
>   complete (DNS resolution, proxy detection, and TCP socket connection,
>   for example) before this method becomes asynchronous. As a result,
>   this method should never be called on a user interface (UI) thread
>   because it might take considerable time (up to several minutes
>   depending on network settings) to complete the initial synchronous
>   setup tasks before an exception for an error is thrown or the method
>   succeeds.

Comment: why don't you use `HttpClient`? It is fully `async` and it supports the Task Based PRogramming model

Comment: Oha, thanks for the info. Are there by any chance even more completely different methods? I would like to know a bit about them all before I commit a lot of time to using on method (unfortunately I have already committed time to HttpWebRequest but I guess that's also time spent learning about VB :)

Comment: Like for example, what about Await and Async?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment i'd use `HttpClient` you can then use `async-await`. Here is an example

```
private async Task DownloadUrlAsync(string url)
{
    HttpClient httpCLient = new HttpClient();
    textBox1.Text = await httpCLient.GetStringAsync(url);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the example, I see that HttpClient and Await/Async are part of 4.5. I am currently working with 4.0, do you think there is a way to salvage my current project by somehow making it failsafe, despite BeginGetResponse being partly synchronous. Such as by trying to connect to the server before starting the Stream/Request? Or would I be better off with ditching these roundabout ways and go for the HttpClient method? (Although that depends if my company can use 4.5)

Comment: A better option might be `WebClient` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: From MSDN: WebClient uses the WebRequest and WebResponse classes to make the actual connections to the Internet resource .... and ....The WebClient class uses the WebRequest class to provide access to resources. So doesn't that make a the WebClient just a more "abstract" method with the same underlying problem?

Comment: True, but they may have solved the problem for you. Check whether the `WebClient` documentation says anything about big delays when initiating an `async` operation.

Comment: Before I delve into that, what about the TcpClient-Class, isn't that the most low-level, basic form using which it is possible to establish web communication?